# Exclude spring-cloud-deployer-spi-scheduler-test-app from implementation jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud

I have created some spring boot applications and have found that the implementation jar contains a direct dependency (org.springframework.cloud : spring-cloud-deployer-spi-scheduler-test-app).  This dependency has a known security vulnerability (CVE-2016-1000027).  I'm not sure what this dependency does, or why something with a designation like '..test-app' ends up in the implementation jar.  I would like to exclude this dependency, but so far I have not had any luck.  I have tried using this in my build.gradle file :

configurations {
all {
exclude module: 'spring-cloud-deployer-spi-scheduler-test-app'
}
}

This works for other dependencies that I need to exclude, but not this one.  Can anyone tell what exactly this module does and how can I exclude it from the implementation jar if possible.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It shouldn't be on your runtime classpath in the first place. Try to figure out where it comes from so you can fix the root problem instead. The `dependencyInsight` task might help: `gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency spring-cloud-deployer-spi-scheduler-test-app`. You probably have a dependency that is declared on the wrong configuration (e.g. `implementation` or `compile` instead of `testImplementation`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that and got nothing :./gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtimeClasspath --dependency spring-cloud-deployer-spi-scheduler-test-app

> Task :dependencyInsight
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':runtimeClasspath'